# Complex Query (With Three Level Subqueries) with Query Builder in Laravel 5?

Tags: mysql, laravel, subquery

I have the query like this:

```
SELECT p.*, t3.gambar_meteran, t3.angka_meteran 
    from pelanggan p 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t1.* 
    FROM tagihan t1 
        JOIN (SELECT no_rek_pelanggan, MAX(created_at) created_at 
            FROM tagihan
            GROUP BY no_rek_pelanggan) t2
        ON t1.no_rek_pelanggan = t2.no_rek_pelanggan 
        AND t1.created_at = t2.created_at) t3
        ON p.no_rek = t3.no_rek_pelanggan`
```

How can I use that complex query in laravel 5.2?

I tried many ways like using `DB::raw`, `DB:statement`, etc.

Comment: Pls share what you have exactly tried and what error message or unexpected behaviour you encountered!

Answer (score 0):

I was solved this problem with it:

```
$temptable=DB::raw("(SELECT t1.* 
           FROM tagihan t1 
           JOIN (SELECT no_rek_pelanggan, MAX(created_at) created_at 
                 FROM tagihan 
                 GROUP BY no_rek_pelanggan) t2 
           ON t1.no_rek_pelanggan = t2.no_rek_pelanggan 
           AND t1.created_at = t2.created_at)  as t3");

        $query = DB::table('pelanggan as p')
        ->select('p.*','t3.gambar_meteran')
        ->leftJoin($temptable,'p.no_rek','=','t3.no_rek_pelanggan')
        ->get();
```

`